# Развитие c#

Tags: c#

Скажите, есть ли какие-нибудь сведения о том, чего стоит ждать в следующих версиях c#? Прочел несколько статей Эрика Липперта, в недавнем прошлом разработчика компилятора для этого языка, так вот он утверждает, что какие-либо новые возможности в язык добавляются очень осторожно, с оглядкой на обратную совместимость. Тем не менее, хотелось бы несколько больше, чем те возможности, что есть сейчас. Может, кто-то что-нибудь слышал на этот счет?

Comment: Вы врятли до конца понимаете что такое мощь C#'a. А какие возможности Вам нужны? В последних версиях включают иновационные подходы, которые ну очень облегчают жизнь программистам, а сами по себе очень важны и мощны. Не хочу конкретизировать.

Comment: не стану утверждать, что во всей полноте владею мощью C#, хотя и у Вас вряд ли есть основания считать, что я не знаю язык. 
Возможности, которые я бы хотел видеть  в языке - более полноправные анонимные типы, нежели те, что есть сейчас, более гибкие обобщения

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по Mono, в сторону кроссплатформенности движутся.
Вот примерный список того, что будет развиваться:

- Data Concurrency
- Object Immutability
- Pure Functions
- Compiler-as-a-service
- C# in C#
- Language Object Model
- Read – Eval – Print Loops
- Meta – programming
- DSL Embedding

Comment: Эээй, Mono - не основная ветвь C# и разрабатывается не его создателями...

Comment: @Niki-Timofe , вы правы. Моя основная работа - winforms, поэтому я не в слишком в кроссплатформенной теме.
Хотя никто не мешает MS взять и купить готовый кроссплатформенный продукт.

Comment: @Drac, вероятно, не хотят покупать по каким-то причинам, иначе давно бы это сделали. Отчего, собственно, вся потенциальная кроссплатформенность идет лесом, к сожалению. Спасибо за ответы